# How do I use Numpy to manipulate masked regions of an image?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-segmentation

How do I use Numpy to manipulate masked regions of an image?

The source image:
[image]

The source mask: 
[image: Mask Image]

If I extract the yellow color from the mask image, then I end up with a Numpy array of Boolean values:

```
True  True  False False False False 
True  True  False False False False 
False False False False False False 
False False False False False False 
False False False False False False 
False False False False False False
```

I then repeat this for all of the other colors in the source mask, and store these mask regions in a list. The same thing is done for the target mask.

The target image:
[image]

The target mask:
[image]

I have a function which takes two images, and transfer the color from the source image to the target image.

So what I want to do, is send matching color regions from my target and source images to my color transfer function (only the two regions should be used so that the color transfer function performs correctly). Once the colors have been transferred for a region, I need to put the resulting color changed region back into the right spot on my target image.

So how do I first, use my mask array to get only the desired piece/region of an image, and then how do I make sure that I can put that piece back in the same spot again?

The two images are loaded with:

```
source_img = spi.imread(source_img, mode="RGB").astype(float)/256
target_img = spi.imread(target_img, mode="RGB").astype(float)/256
```

While the masks are loaded with:

```
target_mask = spi.imread(target_mask, mode="RGB").astype(float)
source_mask = spi.imread(source_mask, mode="RGB").astype(float)
```

And the resulting masks are stored via:

```
target_mask_list = []
source_mask_list = []
for color in list(color_list):
    print(color)
    color_mask = extract_mask(target_mask, color)
    target_mask_list.append(color_mask)
    color_mask = extract_mask(source_mask, color)
    source_mask_list.append(color_mask)
```

The extract_mask function currently works like this:

```
  if color == 'color_name':
      mask = np.all(image == (a,b,c), axis=-1)#.astype(int)  
  return mask
```

Do I do something like this to extract the region?

```
test_list = []
for i in target_mask_list:
    target_test = target_img.all() | i.all() #Extract region
    test_list.append(target_test) # Store region in list
```

Masks are the same size as the images they are for.

Edit, here's a comprehensive visualization of what I am trying to do: [image]

Comment: You provided a good amount of detail, but it's hard to pinpoint your exact problem and question. Could you summarize that in one or two sentences?

Comment: 1. How do I use my mask array to get the "selected" area from an image of equivalent size? 2. How do I put this piece back in it's original place on the unmodified image, after I change it's color?

Comment: It's sort of like the segmentation here: https://github.com/cysmith/neural-style-tf#segmentation, only with multiple colors instead of 2, like in this research paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.07511. But I'm not doing any fancy AI stuff like in those examples, and instead I am only trying to transfer color.

Comment: I have the input images (RGB int array), and their masks (boolean array), but I can't figure out how to use them in the way I described above. I can try to explain things farther if you need me to.

Comment: Edit, here's a comprehensive visualization of what I am trying to do: https://i.imgur.com/pWA0tgO.png

Comment: The mask being the same size as the image complicates things. Is it just a [resized 3x3 grid of colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IKV1.png) or can it be [jagged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BobcV.jpg)? If so, how will you crop out the jagged piece? The source piece and target piece that you feed into your transfer function may not be of the same size.

Comment: The masked regions can be any shape imaginable (as they determine which pixel belongs to which mask). I only used the 3x3 grid of all the possible color options, because I thought a really complex max would confuse people. And yes, the target and the source images can be different sizes, but their masks have to be the same size as they are.

Comment: The source mask needs to use all of the color regions that the target mask uses, but it may also have extra unneeded color regions that can be utilized by other target image/mask combinations (or just simply these unused color regions are ignored). However I think that my code handles this at the moment.

Comment: Maybe I can just make all but the "selected" region be transparent? Instead of trying to separate it and then reattach it.

Comment: Sure, but isn't it really trivial then? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Begin with some `color`. Perhaps iterate through all the different colors in the mask.

```
colors = np.unique(source_mask.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0)

for color in colors:
```

Create copies:

```
    s = source_img.copy()
    t = target_img.copy()
```

Make everything except the selected region "transparent":

```
    s[source_mask != color] = -1
    t[target_mask != color] = -1
```

Throw that into your transfer function:

```
    transfer_img = transfer(s, t)
```

Take the output of your transfer function and overlay it onto your source image:

```
    mask = transfer_image != -1
    source_img[mask] = transfer_img[mask]
```

Comment: It seems that both `s[source_mask != color] = -1`, and `t[target_mask != color] = -1` are merging masks into the images, which results in the mask color being run though the color transfer function.

Comment: It sets everything but the relevant pixels to a "transparent value" of `-1`. Is this different from what you want?

Comment: What is 'transfer' ?

Comment: @jonincanada Some "color transfer function" described in the question. More generally, any function of `s, t`.